# Android: parameters not going through if-else statements?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm using the LogCat to display my values, but its not working through my if statements?

```
    Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    mCamera.setParameters(p);
    mCamera.startPreview();
    Log.d("Torch","MODE AUTO: " + p.getFlashMode() + "," + Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

    //Flash Button
    final Button flashButton = (Button) findViewById(id.camera_flash);
    flashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            Log.d("Torch","MODE : " + p.getFlashMode() + "," + android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(p.getFlashMode() == Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("Off");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE OFF");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("TORCH");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE TORCH");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("ON");
                Log.d("Torch","MODE ON: " + p.getFlashMode() + "," + android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("AUTO");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE AUTO");

            }/*else
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("AUTO");
                Log.d("Torch","MODE AUTO: " + p.getFlashMode() + "," + android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

            }   */      
        }
```

I'm getting `MODE AUTO: off,auto` (within my onCreate) and `MODE: off,off` (within the onClick). These are my tests, so in theory, if my onCreate is `off,auto` then it should pass through `if(p.getFlashMode() == Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)`, but its not?

Any reason why its not going through my if statements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type are they? Unless they're a primitive or wrapper using == won't work and you need to use equals().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON` , `Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF` are `Strings`.([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_OFF))
You need to compare using `equals()`.

`if(p.getFlashMode().equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))`

Comment: Hey Hi I set flash mode to Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON and it is supported flash mode but it is not showing flash on some devices like LG Optimus and Motorolla. If you know any thing about this Please help me?

Comment: You should also check whether flashlight supported and then get ListOf supported flashModes .see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30055092/3496570